# Resetting value of tab to default css state

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I have a question about resetting the state of an active tab class if another tab is clicked.  The code below toggles the class as expected to show a different tab color image however if I click another tab, both tabs are displaying as active.

My question is what do I need to add to reset the active tab back to its default state and activate the newly clicked tab to the active state.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slide-out').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var defaultPos = roundValue($this.css('left'));

        $('.tab', $this).on('click', function(){
            var tab = $(this);                                                                              
            var goTo = tab.attr('slide-To');
            var currentPos = roundValue($this.css('left'));

            if(goTo == currentPos){
               goTo = defaultPos;
            }                                       

            $this.animate({'left': goTo}, 'slow');  
            $(this).toggleClass('handle2-selected');                                    
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove the selected class from all of the tabs, before applying it to the one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should toggle the class on previous tab also as you are doing for the next tab.
or you can write my this code before starting animation.

```
$('.tab').removeClass('handle2-selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of toggleClass you should remove the handle2-selected class from your tabs then apply it to the current one (this)

Something like

```
$('.tab').removeClass('handle2-selected');
tab.addClass('handle2-selected');
```

Update:

To remove the active class on the active tab

```
// check if current clicked tab has the active class or not
if(tab.hasClass('handle2-selected')) {
    // if current clicked tab has active class, remove it
    tab.removeClass('handle2-selected');
    // add other codes for this state if needed
} else {
    // if not then do the normal removing and adding to current tab
    $('.tab').removeClass('handle2-selected');
    tab.addClass('handle2-selected');
}
```

Comment: If I click the tab it works as expected by turning red and if I click the other tab the prev tab toggles back to default and the new tab gets the 'handle2-selected' class.
                                        
The only issue I have is if I want the active tab to go back to default, it stays active.  It only removes the class if I click the other tab.  What do I need to add so that if I click the active tab again, that it too removes the selected class.  I thought adding the remove before animation would do the trick.

Comment: @user1502434 why would you want to remove the active class on the active tab? wouldn't that defeat the purpose? if you really want to remove the active class on the active tab when clicked then you just need to check for the class on the current tab, and if the class exist remove it, I will update my answer

Comment: These are vertical sliding tabs that show different content based on if they slide left vs right however all the tabs and content div have  a default position.  The top tab is clicked and slides right, the class is added to show this tab as active. If I click the same tab again it slides back left to default position and the class should be removed.  As of now the only way the class gets removed is if I click another tab, I need the active tab class to get removed on 2 events. If I click the active and if I click any other tab.

Comment: @user1502434 ok see my updated answer on removal of class on active tab